# How can I get requests to get more than the first table of a site?

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, urllib

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

link = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.health.pa.gov/topics/disease/coronavirus/Pages/Cases.aspx')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')

table = soup.find('table')

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

I am currently trying to make a simple website displaying only the number of COVID-19 cases in a certain county in the US. However, when I run my code, it only gives me data from the first table of the site I am trying to scrape from.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: you are doing `table = soup.find('table')` which will only find the first item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `soup.find('table')` which will only get the first item found. Use `soup.find_all()`:

```py
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

link = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.health.pa.gov/topics/disease/coronavirus/Pages/Cases.aspx')
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(link, 'lxml')

body = soup.find('body') # get the body so you can do soup.find_all() inside it
tables = soup.find_all('table')

for table in tables:

    table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

    for tr in table_rows:
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        row = [i.text for i in td]
        print(row)
```

There is a lot of garbage in the output but it is possible to filter it down by div id/class or table headers.

Output:

```
['\nTotal Cases*', '\u200bDeaths', '\n\u200bNegative']
['60,622', '4,342', '259,210']
['\n\u200bAge Range', '\u200bPercent of Cases*']
['\u200b0-4', '\u200b< 1%']
['\u200b5-12', '\u200b< 1%']
['\u200b13-18', '\u200b1%']
['\u200b19-24', '6%']
['\u200b25-49', '\u200b37%']
['\u200b50-64', '\u200b26%']
['\n\u200b65+', '\u200b28%']
['\n\u200bAge Range', '\u200bPercent of Cases']
['\u200b0-29', '\u200b2%']
['30-49', '\n5%']
['50-64', '10%']
['\u200b65-79', '20%']
['\u200b80+', '19%']
['County', 'Total Cases', 'Negatives\xa0', 'Deaths\xa0']
['Adams', '183', '2035', '6']
['Allegheny', '1582', '21626', '141']
['Armstrong', '57', '955', '5']
['Beaver', '516', '2663', '83']
['Bedford\xa0', '30', '429', '1']
['Berks', '3593', '8171', '207']
['Blair', '32', '1733', '0']
['Bradford', '41', '1030', '2']
['Bucks', '4325', '13245', '410']
['Butler', '202', '2958', '6']
['Cambria', '49', '2315', '1']
['Cameron', '2', '84', '0']
['Carbon', '206', '1575', '17']
['Centre', '129', '1413', '6']
['Chester', '2060', '8001', '218']
['Clarion', '24', '570', '1']
['Clearfield', '33', '721', '0']
['Clinton', '43', '396', '0']
['Columbia', '334', '980', '33']
['Crawford', '21', '811', '0']
['Cumberland', '492', '2745', '41']
['Dauphin', '912', '6987', '41']
['Delaware', '5409', '13810', '466']
['Elk', '6', '229', '1']
['Erie', '129', '2955', '3']
['Fayette', '87', '2370', '4']
['Forest', '7', '45', '0']
['Franklin', '580', '3932', '17']
['Fulton', '11', '144', '0']
['Greene', '27', '567', '1']
['Huntingdon', '204', '588', '0']
['Indiana', '84', '956', '6']
['Jefferson', '7', '397', '0']
['Juniata', '94', '243', '1']
['Lackawanna', '1273', '3994', '141']
['Lancaster', '2428', '11065', '186']
['Lawrence', '72', '960', '7']
['Lebanon', '863', '3501', '19']
['Lehigh', '3396', '10165', '136']
['Luzerne', '2491', '7587', '127']
['Lycoming', '141', '1607', '7']
['McKean', '10', '321', '1']
['Mercer', '83', '1027', '2']
['Mifflin', '57', '942', '0']
['Monroe', '1242', '3917', '70']
['Montgomery', '5697', '23738', '608']
['Montour', '50', '2986', '1']
['Northampton', '2600', '9196', '196']
['Northumberland', '136', '983', '0']
['Perry', '36', '447', '1']
['Philadelphia', '15835', '40378', '1004']
['Pike', '458', '1620', '22']
['Potter', '4', '109', '0']
['Schuylkill', '506', '3022', '15']
['Snyder', '33', '291', '2']
['Somerset', '32', '1129', '1']
['Sullivan', '2', '64', '0']
['Susquehanna', '82', '480', '14']
['Tioga', '16', '400', '1']
['Union', '44', '731', '1']
['Venango', '7', '344', '0']
['Warren', '2', '235', '0']
['Washington', '129', '2989', '4']
['Wayne', '107', '692', '7']
['Westmoreland', '423', '6671', '32']
['Wyoming', '28', '310', '3']
['York', '828', '9630', '16']
['Sex', 'Positive Cases\xa0', 'Percent of Cases*', 'Deaths\xa0']
['Female', '33,184', '55%', '2183']
['Male', '26,784', '44%', '2141']
['Neither', '3', '0%', '0']
['Not reported', '651', '1%', '18']
['Race', 'Positive Cases', 'Percent of Cases** ', 'Deaths\xa0']
['African American/Black', '7073', '12%', '498']
['Asian', '754', '1%', '53']
['White', '15,163', '25%', '1640']
['Other', '312', '1%', '14']
['Not reported', '37,320', '61%', '2137']
['Region', 'Positive', 'Negative', 'Inconclusive\xa0']
['Northcentral\xa0', '918', '10990', '16']
['Northeast', '11707', '39536', '135']
['Northwest', '337', '8699', '18']
['Southcentral', '4187', '33356', '72']
['Southeast', '39125', '121430', '854']
['Southwest', '3026', '45199', '36']
['Facility County', 'Number of Facilities with Cases', 'Number of Cases Among Residents', 'Number of Cases Among Employees', 'Number of Deaths']
['ADAMS', '3', '23', '4', '4']
['ALLEGHENY', '36', '393', '109', '110']
['ARMSTRONG', '1', '5', '6', '3']
['BEAVER', '3', '340', '26', '76']
['BERKS', '25', '710', '100', '139']
['BUCKS', '52', '1376', '320', '328']
['BUTLER', '6', '13', '10', '2']
['CAMBRIA', '1', '1', '.', '0']
['CARBON', '2', '58', '5', '13']
['CENTRE', '3', '16', '11', '4']
['CHESTER', '38', '677', '127', '185']
['CLARION', '1', '1', '1', '0']
['CLEARFIELD', '2', '2', '.', '0']
['COLUMBIA', '3', '95', '33', '29']
['CUMBERLAND', '8', '239', '57', '42']
['DAUPHIN', '3', '229', '49', '26']
['DELAWARE', '39', '1510', '273', '378']
['ERIE', '4', '3', '2', '0']
['FAYETTE', '1', '3', '.', '1']
['FRANKLIN', '5', '79', '13', '8']
['HUNTINGDON', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['INDIANA', '4', '14', '2', '4']
['LACKAWANNA', '15', '560', '96', '121']
['LANCASTER', '32', '608', '174', '163']
['LAWRENCE', '2', '0', '2', '0']
['LEBANON', '4', '81', '14', '13']
['LEHIGH', '26', '590', '122', '106']
['LUZERNE', '19', '404', '71', '93']
['LYCOMING', '3', '68', '12', '8']
['MERCER', '1', '1', '.', '0']
['MIFFLIN', '2', '1', '1', '0']
['MONROE', '8', '146', '44', '35']
['MONTGOMERY', '88', '2153', '110', '506']
['NORTHAMPTON', '14', '634', '154', '128']
['NORTHUMBERLAND', '1', '1', '.', '0']
['PHILADELPHIA', '59', '1614', '8', '410']
['PIKE', '2', '31', '5', '9']
['SCHUYLKILL', '10', '66', '19', '2']
['SUSQUEHANNA', '3', '42', '16', '14']
['UNION', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['WASHINGTON', '3', '6', '2', '1']
['WAYNE', '1', '0', '1', '0']
['WESTMORELAND', '9', '134', '34', '27']
['YORK', '6', '10', '4', '3']
['PENNSYLVANIA', '550', '12937', '2039', '2991']
```

You can put some more logic in there to split each table into its own dictionary or list